# Intermediate Value Theorem for higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I've been asked to construct a proof for the intermediate value theorem in higher dimensions, $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Setup**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let *a* and *b* be points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define the "help" function $g(t)=f(ta+(1-t)b)$

**Assigment**

Prove that if *d* is a number such that $f(a)<d<f(b)$, then there exists a point $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(c)=d$.

Give specific proofs in the cases where *f* is defined on a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$

**Solution (Attempted)**

*g* is a (continuous) function in $\mathbb{R}$, which means we can use the "normal" Intermediate value theorem (proof already given in our book). So for any *d* between $g(t)$ and $g(t')$ there is a *c* such that $g(c)=d$.

We note that $g(0)=f(b)$ and $g(1)=f(a)$. So $g[0,1]=[f(b),f(a)]$.

Is this sufficient? I feel that it's enough to conclude that *f* attains any value *d* between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

Sadly, I am rather clueless on the issue, when *f*'s domain is narrowed to being a rectangle, or a ball.

Comment: What you wrote is enough to me. I am not sure I understand what is being asked by "specific proofs" for the other cases, but can you imagine domains where it does not work ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. $g$ is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[a,b]$.

Comment: @nicomezi: Why not?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I will fix it when I get to my laptop

Comment: As @nicomezi pointed out, the bijection is $t \mapsto ta + (1-t)b$.

Comment: You wrote $g[0,1]=[f(b),f(a)].$ Two problems with this: 1. $f(b)$ might be larger than $f(a)$ and 2. $g[0,1]$ might contain more points than the closed interval determined by $f(b),f(a).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is okay apart from some writing stuff $($like $[f(b),f(a)]$ when we may have $f(a) < f(b))$.

It does not matter that $f$'s domain is a rectangle or a ball, provided they're filled.
What matters for this proof is that the segment $ta+(1-t)b$ lie in the domain.

More generally, what matters here is continuity and connectedness.
The intermediate value theorem is a consequence of two general facts: continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets, and connected sets of the real line are intervals.

Comment: Well yeah, it did seem very backwards to write $g[0,1]=[f(b),f(a)]$. But I'm not entirely sure how to fix it. Notation wise. Do you just say "assume $f(a)<f(b)$ and then $g[0,1]=[f(a),f(b)$ without loss of generality?

Comment: Notice that while $\{g(0),g(1)\} = \{f(a),f(b)\}$, for $x\in(0,1)$ one might even have $g(x)$ outside of $[f(a),f(b)]$ or $[f(b),f(a)]$. Regardless of whether $g(0) = f(a)$ or $g(0) = f(b)$, regardless of whether $f(a)<f(b)$ or $f(a) > f(b)$, and regardless of whether $g([0,1]) = [f(a),f(b)]$ or strictly contains it, the theorem holds. The usual way to say it with words: for each $y$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there is some $c$ between $0$ and $1$ with $g(c) = y$.

Comment: For instance, consider $f(x) = x^2$. With $a = -1$ and $b = 2$ we have $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = 4$. But we don't have $f([a,b]) = [1,4]$, we have $f([a,b]) = [0,4]$. The theorem still holds, and for each $y\in(1,4)$ we can find $x\in(-1,2)$ with $f(x) = y$.